# Basic swing ui use in a different 'main' method beside default

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

until now I have used the default main function coming with google tool kit, for activating the the gui for my program,  now I'm looking forward to add a gui one by one to a other main program, i have added the  class object  but when running the program only the frame appears and labels, while my  fields and buttons need a click-over / click on the space to make them visible, why?

```
public LoginGui() {
        initialize();
        uc = new UserCntrl();   
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 415);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); // i have added this line
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        // init login GUI
        LoginGui loginGuiWindow;
        try {
            loginGuiWindow = new LoginGui();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A guess: could you be adding components to your JFrame *after* setting it visible? If so, don't do that. call `setVisible(true)` after adding all components.
- Also, don't use null layout. Use the layout managers and a `pack()` call if you want to avoid some terrible headaches should you want to upgrade or modify your GUI.

Comment: Thank you, yes that is the problem, i was setting visible at the begining not after all components where added,  i will look into pack() also. :)

Comment: @BogdanM.: you're welcome. More importantly, look into use of layout managers and avoidance of use of `null` layout.